# change background images on mousewheel(scroll down). Change image back when scrollup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mousewheel

I am trying to change a background image on scroll down - something like this [webpage](https://www.chelseacollective.com)

I am able to change the image on scroll down however there is no control as it changes many times. I want it to just change once on scroll down. And then when I scroll up I want it to change back just once. However as you [will see here at this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejxgkc9d/) it changes many times when you scroll up or down. Ideally I would also like to use the index in the array to change the images but want to solve the original issue regarding the scrolldown/scrollup first.

**html**

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="bgImage"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bgImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

body, html, #scene, .bgImage {
  height: 100%; 
}

.trees {
  background: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-69o3lsK5MrQ/ThhlOTxGQlI/AAAAAAAAEfY/e0AJF-6sKBw/s1600/bret_hart_-_bret_hart_74.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**JS**

```
var pages = ['home','urban','trees','people'];
var page = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').on('mousewheel', function(e){
       if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
          jQuery('.bgImage').addClass('trees');
       }
       else{
            jQuery('.bgImage').removeClass('trees');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Play with the flags then!

Comment: @Rayon what does this mean?

Comment: `Boolean-flags` to apply conditions upon!

Comment: @Rayon could you provide an answer to elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been deprecated, you should be using `on` instead: [http://api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @neilsimp1 thanks! updated question. any idea how to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag or counter to check if the background should change.
I made something like the page you mention about ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ck8uste/4/)).

On the code, i separate the content into 4 parts and use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` for the transition between the contents.
May be this is what you wanted.

Comment: This is good, but still doesn't solve the issue of when you scroll quickly it changes many times. I want it to be more controlled so that it only changes once per scroll, no matter how much you scroll

Comment: you can give flag too when at the start transition and end transition to prevent scrolling too fast. As you can see on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ck8uste/7/)

Comment: @phantom the scroll event won't triggered when the animation flag is not true. so it prevent the user to scroll too fast.

Comment: but if  you scroll very fast once, you will see that the content changes many times. it should only change once on each individual scroll

Comment: @phantom have you check my updated JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ck8uste/7/)